# Adding Video to CartoDB

Tags: carto, layers, youtube

I am trying to Add a layer with Youtube in the info window as follows

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="cartodb-popup v2">
  <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
  <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
    <div class="cartodb-popup-content">
      <p>
        <iframe width="380" height="175" src="{{description}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```js
$('#map').ready(function(e){
    cartodb.createVis(map, 'https://internetadventureclub.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/4d794d4a-8b43-11e5-ada8-0ecd1bab222de5/viz.json')
        .on('done', function(vis,layers) {
          // get sublayer 0 and set the infowindow template
          var sublayer = layers[1].getSubLayer(0);

          sublayer.infowindow.set('sanitizeTemplate',false);

         //  sublayer.infowindow.set('template', $('#infowindow_template').html());
         }).on('error', function() {
           console.log("some error occurred");
         });
  });
```

The moment we add other data layers in addition to the video layer. This seems to make the video layer stop working.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to add another data layer with interactivity? That is the problem. There is just one possible interactivity layer on each map, so you would need to define both data layers as sublayers. Then you could use a second infowindow template for each one.

Given that you are using `createVis`to build your map, you could add a second layer in the CartoDB Editor, and then in your Javascript, retrieve it as follows: 

`sublayer2=layers[1].getSubLayer(1);`

Once you have your sublayers, you could set a different infowindow for each one.

Check [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/ernesmb/93c9c083f3b0897c5c75), working with two sublayers/two different infowindows. It uses `createLayer` instead of `createVis`, but it will work the same regarding interactivity.

Hope this helps